# uC/OS hardware register read

Tags: c, embedded

I am trying to use the low power timer on the Freescale FRDM K64F, with IAR as design framework and uC/OS as operating system. I read the manual and I found that the timer is controlled by means of a bunch of registers, but I am getting in trouble with the register reading and writing.

At first I am just trying to read a register with the code attached below. The code stucks as soon as the read line is reached: the line “after read” is not printed on terminal. Searching through the debugger, I found out that the hardfault_handler exception is raised. I am not a software expert, so: does anyone have an idea about what is the problem here? It should be something related with the OS, but I can’t understand what. I said I am not a software expert, so, should I have forgot to tell something important, please let me know. Thanks in advance.

```
#include "fsl_interrupt_manager.h"

#include  <math.h>
#include  <lib_math.h>
#include  <cpu_core.h>

#include  <app_cfg.h>
#include  <os.h>

#include  <fsl_os_abstraction.h>
#include  <system_MK64F12.h>
#include  <board.h>

#include  <bsp_ser.h>


/*
*********************************************************************************************************
*                                            LOCAL DEFINES
*********************************************************************************************************
*/


/*
*********************************************************************************************************
*                                       LOCAL GLOBAL VARIABLES
*********************************************************************************************************
*/

static  OS_TCB       AppTaskStartTCB;
static  CPU_STK      AppTaskStartStk[APP_CFG_TASK_START_STK_SIZE];


/*
*********************************************************************************************************
*                                      LOCAL FUNCTION PROTOTYPES
*********************************************************************************************************
*/

static  void  AppTaskStart (void  *p_arg);




int  main (void)
{
    OS_ERR   err;

#if (CPU_CFG_NAME_EN == DEF_ENABLED)
    CPU_ERR  cpu_err;
#endif

    hardware_init();
    GPIO_DRV_Init(switchPins, ledPins);


#if (CPU_CFG_NAME_EN == DEF_ENABLED)
    CPU_NameSet((CPU_CHAR *)"MK64FN1M0VMD12",
                (CPU_ERR  *)&cpu_err);
#endif

    OSA_Init();                                                 /* Init uC/OS-III.                                      */

    OSTaskCreate(&AppTaskStartTCB,                              /* Create the start task                                */
                 "App Task Start",
                  AppTaskStart,
                  0u,
                  APP_CFG_TASK_START_PRIO,
                 &AppTaskStartStk[0u],
                 (APP_CFG_TASK_START_STK_SIZE / 10u),
                  APP_CFG_TASK_START_STK_SIZE,
                  0u,
                  0u,
                  0u,
                 (OS_OPT_TASK_STK_CHK | OS_OPT_TASK_STK_CLR | OS_OPT_TASK_SAVE_FP),
                 &err);

    OSA_Start();                                                /* Start multitasking (i.e. give control to uC/OS-III). */

    while (DEF_ON) {                                            /* Should Never Get Here                                */
        ;
    }
}





static  void  AppTaskStart (void *p_arg)
{
  OS_ERR    os_err;

  (void)p_arg;                                                /* See Note #1                                          */

  char string[800];

  CPU_Init();                                                 /* Initialize the uC/CPU Services.                      */
  Mem_Init();                                                 /* Initialize the Memory Management Module              */
  Math_Init();                                                /* Initialize the Mathematical Module                   */


  int * PSR = (int *) 0x42040004;

  BSP_Ser_Init(115200u);

  APP_TRACE_DBG(("Blinking RGB LED...\n\r"));


  int value;

  APP_TRACE_DBG(("Before read\n"));
  value=*PSR;
  APP_TRACE_DBG(("After read\n"));

  APP_TRACE_DBG(("Before sprintf\n"));       
  sprintf(string,"Value is %d\n",value);
  APP_TRACE_DBG(("After sprintf\n"));

}
```

Comment: [PSR is a privileged register](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/CHDBIBGJ.html)

Comment: PSR is a specific register of the low power timer, it is not the program status register.

Comment: Are you sure about the address. Take notes that the correct declaration should be `(volatile uint32_t *)(0x42040004)`. Could you link the datasheet of mcu?

Comment: https://www.google.it/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://cache.freescale.com/files/microcontrollers/doc/ref_manual/K64P144M120SF5RM.pdf&ved=0ahUKEwi1t9jtio_PAhWDiSwKHWtAAwAQFggeMAA&usg=AFQjCNHf2bM0kd4CHzoSatT0Jtnwb6GguA this is the link, sorry for the mess. At page 171 you can find the memory map and the explanation of what aliased addresses are (basically some addresses are replicated in order to have the single bits addressable).  If you are interested, at page 1095 you can find details about the low power timer, and you can understand exactly what is that address.

Comment: Any reason you define the address manually and not use the MCU CMSIS header? Use that header.

Comment: Address of `LPTMR0_PSR` is  `0x40040004`: page `1097`.

Comment: @LPs that is the "regular" address, I am using an "aliased" address, that allows to access to a single bit of the 4 byte word addressed by 0x40040004. With 0x42040004, I am addressing just the first bit of the word whose address is 0x40040004. By the way, if I use 0x40040004, the behavior is exactly the same. Unfortunately, changing to (volatile uint32_t *)(0x42040004) did not help either.

Comment: @Olaf I did not know CMSIS header. I had a glance at it, and I found some time managing functions; however, none of them seem to control the low power timer. For my project I need to use either the low power timer or the flexitimer. Moreover, they are the only timers with the resolution I need (microseconds), the others seem to have a milliseconds resolution.

Comment: There should be ah header with the register definitions (resp. macros and constants). And the timers have that resolution you program them to have, using prescaler and compare register, etc. First rule in embedded is to have the reference manual (or however it is called) at hand.

Comment: Well. So `0x4204004` is `bit 1` of `LPTMR0_CSR`. If you want to "point" `bit 0` of `LPTMR0_PSR` you must use address `0x42040080` (offset is `32*32` bits of `LPTMR0_PSR`) of . You can find a good explanation [at this link](http://www.scienceprog.com/bit-band-operations-with-arm-cortex-microcontrollers/). This clearly does not explain why the firmware stops working as far as you dereference that address.

Comment: I found by means of IAR debugger that those registers I am trying to access are not addressed. In place of the address number, e.g. 0x4000000, you get a -------- (I have italian keyboard and I cannot format the addresses). I just don't know why. Anyone knows what those dashes mean in IAR?